# link_to helper method not working with friendlyId Gem in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, friendly-id

It's strange it works on my dev environment but when I deploy it continues to link to the product ID.

I am using Rails 4.04 and the FriendlyId v5 Gem. On development when I do this:

```
<%= link_to image_tag(product.photos.first.image.url(:feed)), product %>
```

It generates a picture with a link that looks like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/products/my-product-slug
```

But when I deploy to production the same code generates

```
http://myprodserver.com/products/68
```

Why would this be happening?

Comment: Have you done the migration for friendlyID at production?

Comment: Yep - made sure to do that.

Comment: This is weird. I just recently used FriendlyID for one of my app, and it worked fine on production. Ruling migration out; with this behavior, I can only say that the new build may not be passed to Production. :\

Comment: when you say link_to("text", product) how does rails get the URL for product? Thats the heart of the issue here.

Comment: I just have it like this `link_to("Visit", product)`, and in the `show` action - `@product = Product.friendly.find(params[:id]).to_s.downcase`

Comment: Yep, I have that too. And it works in dev but not in production. So right now I'm looking at polymorphic_routes::polymorphic_url because that's where the URL get's generated in Rails.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53881/discussion-between-kiddorails-and-asolberg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed with you, the problem is that you are *explicitly* generating the `slug` field in your model.

Though you have correctly configured `FriendlyID` in your model - but in production, there are still many products for which `slug` field may not have value. You need to generate the slugs for them before you can access the route correctly (as intended).

I take that the *slug generation* part is in some sort of some callback. So, in production, you can do:

`Product.find_each(&:save)` to create slugs.

FriendlyID should then work perfectly! :)

Good luck. :)